# Translation invariance of features in convolutional encoder-decoders

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

A big part of using convolutional layers is translation invariance, i.e., features are detected regardless of their position in the image.

In a convolutional encoder-decoder that maps from an image input to, say, an object segmentation, are the features in the deconvolutional/decoding layers still translation invariant? If I were to take the pre-final decoding layer's output, would those features capture the positional information of different objects?

[image: convolutional encoder-decoder architecture]